# List and filter files in Rust

Tags: file-system, rust

I'm learning Rust and looking for better/cleaner ways to list all file names that do not start with `filter`, given a `pathname` as a parameter.

```
    fn list_files(&self, pathname: &PathBuf, filter: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error> {
        fs::read_dir(pathname).map(|read_dir| {
            read_dir
                .filter_map(|res| {
                    res.map(|entry| {
                        entry
                            .path()
                            .strip_prefix(pathname)
                            .ok()
                            .map(|path| {
                                if path.starts_with(filter) {
                                    None
                                } else {
                                    Some(path.to_path_buf())
                                }
                            })
                            .flatten()
                    })
                    .ok()
                    .flatten()
                })
                .collect()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're returning error only in case of `read_dir` failure. Not sure if anyone ever really needs it, but you could change upmost `Some()` to `Ok()`, remove `.ok()` and fix the signature so that my version works just like yours. Note: the code below wasn't tested. I didn't like nested structure of your function, so I came up with this:

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn list_files(pathname: &PathBuf, filter: &str) -> Option<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    Some(fs::read_dir(pathname).ok()?
        .filter_map(|entry| {
            Some(
                entry
                    .ok()?
                    .path()
                    .strip_prefix(pathname)
                    .ok()?
                    .to_path_buf(),
            )
        })
        .filter(|path| path.starts_with(filter))
        .collect())
}
```

Explanation: `.ok()` maps `Result<T, K>` to `Option<T>`, `?` operator returns early in case if `Option` or `Result` aren't `Some()`/`Ok()`